# MySQL has a differnet IP from the host computer?

Tags: mysql, networking

I'm working on a clients computer network.  On the network, there are two computers A and B lets call them.

Computer A has an IPv4 of 192.168.250.50 according to the ipconfig

Computer B has an IPv4 of 10.0.89.17.

Compuer A can ping computer B but computer B cannot ping computer A.

Computer A has a MySQL 5.6 database on it.  The workbench connects with IP 127.0.0.1 so it's local.

However, to connect to the database from computer B, so far the only way we had it work was to turn off the windows firewall completely on Computer A and instead of connecting to 192.168.250.50:3306 as you would expect, you have to use 192.168.251.2:3306.  This confuses me as I thought the MySQL would have the same IP as the host given the connection string is 127.0.0.1, and also I've just never seen them be different like that.

On computer A I tried making firewall rules to allow computer B to talk to it but we still cannot ping it (while firewall on OR off)  or connect to the database while the firewall is on (though we can while it is off).  Any ideas as to what may be going on here?

Comment: Usually when you can't ping a pc, it might be caused by the network and sharing setting. In windows 10 "Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > Network and Sharing Centre > Advanced sharing settings" .. need to "turn on network discovery". As for the mysql, I'm not quite sure but you could check a few things like is there any additional IP on the pc where the mysql user was created like "user@192.168.251.2" instead of "user@%" or "user@192.168.251.50"?  Or maybe there's a 'bind-address' setting in my.ini/my.cnf?

Comment: You also need to give access to "computer A's" mysql port in the firewall.